# Confusing probability question, please help me

Tags: probability

> In a pool of $26$ lowercase alphabets, $26$ uppercase alphabets and $10$ digits ($0$ to $9$), there are total $62$ different characters. Four characters are selected randomly with replacement.
>
> What is the probability of getting two different letters and two different digits?

The confusing part is that I do not know if uppercase and lowercase of the same alphabet are considered the same letter.

Comment: The issue there is with the question - ambiguous wording. Also, are we drawing with replacement or without?

Comment: with replacement

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: my train of thought now is, since order is not important, let's say I will choose a letter first, there are 52 possibilities, after I choice the first letter, then only left with 50 possibility for the 2nd letter, assuming they are different letters. Then I will choose a digit and another different digit.

Comment: so it will be, 52/62 * 50/62 * 10/62 * 9/62, but this is different from the answer provided

Comment: To solve you need to address  2 ambiguities: (a) drawing with replacement or not, as T.Linnel pointed out; (b) whether lower case and upper case instances of the same letter are considered different letters.  If I had this question in an exam or homework, I would solve for the 4 possibilities to get an A+.

Comment: @Anlinyang that would be **very specifically** the probability of the first chosen character is a letter, the second chosen character is a different letter (*counting upper and lower of the same letter as "the same letter"*), the third chosen character being a number and the fourth chosen character being a different number.  You neglected to take into account the order in which these can occur.  I would consider the string $5aC4$ to have two different letters and two different numbers.  To account for the ordering, you should multiply by something extra... what might that be?

Comment: As for "*order not mattering*", I would recommend not approaching that way because 1) you make mistakes like you just did, using formulae for as though order did matter when you just said you didn't want it to, and 2) the sample space will no longer be equiprobable making it so you can't just count how many favorable cases there are and divide by the sample space size.  The number of outcomes where order doesn't matter would be $\binom{4+62-1}{62-1}$, however some outcomes such as having one each of a,b,c,d occurs with a whopping $4!=24$ times larger probability than having four a's.

Answer (score 1):

We have to determine the probability that a random word of length $4$ over the alphabet $\{{\tt a,\ldots,z,A,\ldots, Z,0,\ldots 9}\}$ satisfies certain conditions. There are $62^4=14\,776\,336$ equiprobable words.

All admissible words consist of four different symbols. Two of the symbols have to be alphabetical and two of them have to be numerical. I assume that  pairs of type $\{{\tt a, A}\}$ are forbidden. We then can choose two letters from the alphabet in ${26\choose2}=325$ ways and then realize each of these choices as symbol pair in $4$ ways: $\{{\tt a, b}\}$,$\{{\tt a, B}\}$,$\{{\tt A, b}\}$,$\{{\tt A, B}\}$.  The numerical pair can be chosen in ${10\choose2}=45$ ways. When the four symbols have been chosen we can arrange them in $4!=24$ ways. It follows that there are $325\cdot4\cdot45\cdot24=1\,404\,000$ admissible words.

The probability $p$ in question then comes to
$$p={1\,404\,000\over14\,776\,336}\doteq0.0950\ .$$

Comment: Excellent answer. The logic of solving the question is so clear. However, can you please elaborate on more why 26C2 needs to times 4?